# Prove that $\frac{x} {x+1}$ is increasing

Tags: monotone-functions

I am trying to prove this function $y = \frac{x} {x+1}$ is increasing. I tried doing by induction: let $n = 1$, then clearly $\frac 1 2 \leq \frac 2 3$ so it's true. But I get stuck on the inductive step, where I'm not even sure how to manipulate the fraction. I have tried multiplying it by various things like $\frac {x+1} {x+1}$ but I guess some more clever manipulation is needed. Any hints would be appreciated here

Comment: Induction would only prove it is increasing on the natural numbers,  you need to show it is true on real numbers..  Hint:   Add and subtract one in the numerator.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is decreasing

Comment: Hint : $y = 1 - \frac{1}{x+1}.$  As $x$ increases, what is happening to the fraction $\frac{1}{x+1}$?

Comment: @user2661923 as $x$ increases, the fraction gets smaller and $y$ gets bigger - I get it now, thank you all!

Comment: If you can use calculus, you can show that the derivative is always positive

Comment: Can only use induction on natural numbers.  The real number equivalence is to prove that $x< y \implies \frac x{x+1} < \frac y{y+1}$.  We can do that by manipulating $\frac x{x+1}= \frac{x+1 - 1}{x+1} = \frac{x+1}{x+1} -\frac 1{x+1} = 1-\frac 1{x+1}$.  So we just need to show that $x <y \implies 1-\frac 1{x+1} < \frac 1-\frac 1{y+1}$.  Can you do that?

Comment: To reiterate Jose Carlos Santos and user2661923 comments, though, this function *isn't* actually increasing.  consider $-1.1 < -0.9$ but $f(-1.1) = \frac {-1.1}{-1.1+1}=\frac{-1.1}{-0.1}= 11 > 0$ but $f(-0.9) = \frac {-0.9}{-0.9 + 1} = \frac {-0.9}{0.1} = -9 < 0$.  So $f(-1.1) > f(-0.9)$ even then $-1.1 < -0.9$.  So it is *not* increasing.... it is increasing on $(-1, \infty)$ and on $(-\infty, -1)$ individually but it is not increasing on the whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $x\in(-1,\infty)$. Then, if $y>x$,$$\frac y{y+1}-\frac x{x+1}=\frac{y-x}{(1+x)(1+y)}>0,$$and therefore $\frac y{y+1}-\frac x{x+1}>0\left(\iff\frac y{y+1}>\frac x{x+1}\right)$.

Note, however, that if you consider that the domain of the expression $\frac x{x+1}$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$, then the statement is false: $-2<0$, but$$\frac{-2}{-2+1}=2>0=\frac0{0+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}>0$ hence the function is increasing

Comment: No, see the answer of José Carlos Santos and subsequent comments.

Answer (score 0):

$y(x)=\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x+1-1}{x+1} = \frac{x+1}{x+1} + \frac{-1}{x+1} =1 - \frac{1}{x+1}$

In the last term we have the reciprocal value of $x+1$ which is decreasing.

Multiplying a decreasing expresssion with a negative number like $-1$ makes it increasing.

And adding the constant $1$ does not change the direction, so the complete rhs is overall increasing.